# Work with different module.js moodle

Tags: moodle

I´ve a problem in moodle.

I have a  config module.js (`moodle/mod/imscp`) like this:

```
// line 198 aprox.

  // layout
        YAHOO.widget.LayoutUnit.prototype.STR_COLLAPSE = M.str.moodle.hide;
        YAHOO.widget.LayoutUnit.prototype.STR_EXPAND = M.str.moodle.hide;

        imscp_layout_widget = new YAHOO.widget.Layout('imscp_layout', {
            minWidth: 920,
            minHeight:1200,
            units: [
                { position: 'left', body: 'imscp_toc', header: M.str.imscp.toc, width: 0, resize: true, gutter: '2px 5px 5px 2px', collapse: false, minWidth:0},
                { position: 'center', body: '<div id="imscp_content"></div>', gutter: '2px 5px 5px 2px', scroll: true}
            ]
        });
```

For not use the `imscp_toc` but I need in another course (old course) an another config.

Is possible working with different module.js for X course or X themes?

Comment: So, you want Moodle to choose between two different javascript file, based on the course in which the user is in. Right?

Comment: There are several ways to do this (e.g. Moodle processing imscp's view.php pass `imscp_hide: true` to the javascript module, if the user is in a specific course). If this is what you want, I can answer your question.